# Create DBLINK from oracle to SYBASE

Tags: windows, oracle11g, sybase, dblink

I have a Windows server 2019 with Oracle Database 11.2.0.4 installed on it.
There is a server with SYBASE 12.5.3 on Windows Server 2019.
How to make DBLINK from Oracle to SYBASE?
More precisely, where can I get the SYBASE driver for windows ODBC x64?

Comment: I never had to do that, but - as you're on 11g, did you read "Oracle Database Gateways Documentation" (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14449_01/doc/index.htm). It contains installation and configuration guide, as well as - specifically - "Database Gateway for Sybase User's Guide" document.

Comment: Littlefoot, thanks for the guide, but there are no installation instructions there. The problem is in creating the connection itself.

Comment: Are you looking for installation instructions for the Sybase ODBC driver?  There are several- you'd need to go to the vendor of the particular driver you are using and get the installation instructions from them.

Comment: Justin Cave, i looking for a way to connect from Oracle to Sybase to run queries. There are a lot of instructions on the Internet for creating a DBlink between Oracle and mssql, postgre, mysql using ODBC. But there are practically no instructions for connecting from Oracle to Sybase via ODBC, much less drivers for this.